# How can I print a string and pause when there's a full stop or "..." in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, iteration, pause

I'm trying to make a program in Ruby that prints text out and pauses both for every full stop "." or "..." in a string. I've got this so far but don't know where to take it next.

```
def talk(text, speed = 0.008)
    pause = speed * 100
    text.each_char do |char| 
        print char
        if char == '.'
            sleep(pause)
        end
        sleep(speed) 
    end
    return
end

# e.g. talk("I can see something... It's getting closer... Oh no.")
```

It pauses fine for one full stop but obviously doesn't work for three in a row as it just repeats the pause three times. I'm more of a beginner and struggling to find a solution. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion -- print all the `.`s as they appear, sleeping before printing the next character.

```rb
def talk(text, speed = 0.008)
    pause = speed * 100
    last_char = nil # keep track of the previous character.

    text.each_char do |char|
        if char == '.' 
            # no sleep at all for periods
            print('.')
        else
            # we're going to print something, if the last character was a period,
            # pause before doing it.  
            sleep(pause) if last_char == '.'
            print char
            # finally, a regular sleep 
            sleep(speed)
        end
        # and update the last character we saw
        last_char = char
    end
end
```

Of course, there's lots of different ways to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
def talk(text, speed = 0.008)
  pause = speed * 100
  r = /(\.{3}|\.)/
  text.split(r).each do |str|
    if str.match?(r)
      sleep(pause)
    else
      print str
    end
  end
  puts
end
```

```
talk("Mary had .a lit...tle .lamb", 0.04)
  #=> Mary had a little lamb
              ^     ^      ^
```

A four-second delay occurred after each character indicated by a party hat was printed.

The steps are as follows.

```
text = "Mary had .a lit...tle .lamb"
speed = 0.04
pause = speed * 100
r = /(\.{3}|\.)/
```

This regular expression reads, "match three periods or (`|`) one period in capture group 1" (the capture group being defined by the parentheses)". This is not the same as `/(\.|\.{3})/`, which would match each period of each group of three individually (that is, `\.` before `|` would succeed for every period, part of a group or not).

```
a = text.split((r))
  #=> ["Mary had ", ".", "a lit", "...", "tle ", ".", "lamb"]
```

See [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split), which explains the need for the capture group, to include the splitting strings in the array returned.

Continuing,

```
a.each do |str|
  if str.match?(r)
    sleep(pause)
  else
    print str
  end
end
```

This prints (without a newline character) `"Mary had "`, sleeps for four seconds, prints `"a lit"`, sleeps for another four seconds, and so on.

```
puts
```

This last statement is needed to print a newline character to terminate the line.

---

Another way is to make a few small change to the method given in the question.

```
def talk(text, speed = 0.008)
  pause = speed * 100
  text.squeeze('.').each_char do |char| 
    if char == '.'
      sleep(pause)
    else
      print char
    end
  end
  puts
end
```

See [String#squeeze](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze) which converts each string of two or more periods to one period.

This method differs from the earlier one in its treatment of two or more than three periods in a row.